# How to set connection timeout when I use HttpWebRequest to do asynchronous programming？

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I want to control the timeout of http request.
How to set connection timeout when I use HttpWebRequest to do asynchronous programming with .NET Framework?

I've tried implement it in callback of BeginGetResponse, but it seems the callback will be called after getting the response, so it does not work.

Env: .net framework

```
    /// <summary><para>Begins an asynchronous request to an Internet resource.</para></summary>
    /// <param name="callback">The <see cref="T:System.AsyncCallback" /> delegate </param>
    public override IAsyncResult BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, object state) => throw null;
```

Comment: See either [ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepointidletime) or [ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.connectionleasetimeout). Read the Remarks sections to determine which one is a better fit (i.e., not the same thing)

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to use `HttpClient`?